# How to Solve JSON Validation Expecting 'EOF'

Tags: json

I am working on a hospital database system where I use JSON to display patients' data I encountered a JSON error and have been validating with http://jsonlint.com/.
this is the error I get when validating with http://jsonlint.com/;

```
Error: Parse error on line 9:
... Delete<\/a>"]   ]} <div style = "borde
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

This is my JSON script that generates that error. The script has some demo data already entered;

```
    {
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 2,
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "data": [
        ["63", "emma", "+256702270442", "$0", " <a type=\"button\" class=\"btn editbutton\" title=\"Edit\" data-toggle = \"modal\" data-id=\"63\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"> <\/i> Edit<\/a>  <a type=\"button\" class=\"btn detailsbutton inffo\" title=\"Info\" data-toggle = \"modal\" data-id=\"63\"><i class=\"fa fa-info\"> <\/i> Info<\/a> <a class=\"btn green\" title=\"History\" style=\"color: #fff;\" href=\"patient\/medicalHistory?id=63\"><i class=\"fa fa-stethoscope\"><\/i> History<\/a> <a class=\"btn invoicebutton\" title=\"Payment\" style=\"color: #fff;\" href=\"finance\/patientPaymentHistory?patient=63\"><i class=\"fa fa-money-bill-alt\"><\/i> Payment<\/a> <a class=\"btn delete_button\" title=\"Delete\" href=\"patient\/delete?id=63\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i> Delete<\/a>"]
    ]
}
< div style = "border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;" >
<h4 > A PHP Error was encountered < /h4>
<p > Severity: Core Warning < /p>
<p > Message: Module 'SourceGuardian'already loaded < /p>
<p > Filename: Unknown < /p>
<p > Line Number: 0 < /p>
<p > Backtrace: < /p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

json format is a key-value pair structure format, so the last part of your json data is  not a json suited format, you must provide a key and provide the value as the html that you get

for your data it would be something like this

```
    {
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 2,
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "data": [
        ["63", "emma", "+256702270442", "$0", " <a type=\"button\" class=\"btn editbutton\" title=\"Edit\" data-toggle = \"modal\" data-id=\"63\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"> <\/i> Edit<\/a>  <a type=\"button\" class=\"btn detailsbutton inffo\" title=\"Info\" data-toggle = \"modal\" data-id=\"63\"><i class=\"fa fa-info\"> <\/i> Info<\/a> <a class=\"btn green\" title=\"History\" style=\"color: #fff;\" href=\"patient\/medicalHistory?id=63\"><i class=\"fa fa-stethoscope\"><\/i> History<\/a> <a class=\"btn invoicebutton\" title=\"Payment\" style=\"color: #fff;\" href=\"finance\/patientPaymentHistory?patient=63\"><i class=\"fa fa-money-bill-alt\"><\/i> Payment<\/a> <a class=\"btn delete_button\" title=\"Delete\" href=\"patient\/delete?id=63\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i> Delete<\/a>"]
    ],
    "moredata": "<div style = \"border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;\" > <h4 > A PHP Error was encountered < \/h4> <p > Severity: Core Warning < \/p> <p > Message: Module \"SourceGuardian\"already loaded < \/p> <p > Filename: Unknown < \/p> <p > Line Number: 0 < \/p> <p > Backtrace:< \/p><\/div>"
}
```

PS: Don't forget to correctly escape the html data!